# How to get the name from the array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to JavaScript and I am trying to extract the name Sam from the array. The output that I'm getting is name. How do I get Sam? Thank you in advance. I apologize but I know this is a fairly novice question.

I am trying to loop by using forEach.

```
let Person = {
  name: ['Sam']
}

let handler = Object.keys(Person)

handler.forEach(function(element){
  console.log(element)
})
```

Comment: Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) if you want key **and** value or use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) if you only want values.

Comment: If your structure is just that, you can do `let name = Person.name[0]`;

Comment: do as @zero298 says or you can use `Person[element]` as element is the key and `Person` is the Object whose property's value you are trying to access

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Just curious but what if i want the output like this: name=Sam. Is there gonna be a different approach than just looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) only gives you **keys**
- Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) if you want key **and** value
- Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) if you only want **values**

```js
let Person = {
  name: ['Sam']
}

for (const fn of ["values", "keys", "entries"]) {
  console.log(`Using: Object.${fn}()`);
  for (const v of Object[fn](Person)) {
    console.log(v);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just curious but what if i want the output like this: name=Sam. Is there gonna be a different approach than just looping?

Comment: @paaswhatever If you know the structure and index, you can dereference directly.  I think the confusing thing is that you have set `name` to an Array.  To me, a name is singular.  It doesn't quite make sense that it would be an Array.  Since you know the structure, you can just do `Person.name[0]`.

Comment: Actually this will be a part of a filter where in the name array, the values will keep coming in so it might have one name now, but in the future there could be 15 or 20 names. and then there will be an age array with again 15 or 20 ages so i doubt if i would be able to use Person.name[0]. So basically the structure will keep on changing with more values coming in. So i don't know if you have any better solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Object.keys use Object.values

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that your name array is located under the key `name`, then access it directly

```js
const person = { name: ['Sam'] };

console.log(person.name);
console.log(person.name[0]);
```

Otherwise, use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to enumerate the values in the object, but you might get more values than simply the names array and you will have to find out which value contains the names you are looking for:

```js
const person = { name: ['Sam'], anotherProp: 'hello' };

console.log(Object.values(person));
```

Using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is not helpful in this situation as if you use it, it means that you know under which property is located your name array, and if this is the case, simply access the array directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Object.keys()` you can get the value by using `object[key]` bracket notation or `object.key` dot notation.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key]);
```

```js
let Person = {
  name: ['Sam']
}

Object.keys(Person).forEach(name => console.log(`${name} = ${Person[name]}`));
```

Comment: It's definitely a good answer but what if i want the output like this: name=Sam. Is there gonna be a different approach than just looping?

Comment: It's just a matter of interpolating a template literal or concating a string literal. See updated answer using a template literal.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Person = {
  name: ['Sam',"Bob","Alice"]
 }

 let count = Person.name.length;
 for(let i = 0; i<count; i++){
  console.log( Person.name[i])
 }
```